# Status report says database out of date, but update.php and drush say up-to-date

Tags: database

Drupal 7.39, all modules updated to their latest version using Drush 6.6.0. When I look at the status report it says 'database out of date'. When I do `drush updb` or call `update.php` both report that the database is up-to-date.

How can I find out where the problem is?

Comment: This may help: https://www.drupal.org/node/1263908

Comment: @rooby Thanks! That helped. 1 module was acting up. So I changed the version in the system table to the version of the lowest update, ran the update.php and now the status report is green.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I took to solve the problem. @rooby gave the URL that helped to determine which module.

As you can read on the given URL (https://www.drupal.org/node/1263908) the problem is caused by a module having a version of -1 in the system table. The URL has instructions how to find out which one is acting up. I've followed the one in this comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1263908#comment-9059569

This basically means:

- open [drupalroot]/modules/system/system.install
- find the line `$requirements['update']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_ERROR;` In drupal 7.39 this is on line 412
- add the watchdog line as described: `watchdog('module update db', $module); // <-ADDED THIS LINE`
- open the status page again
- now open the watchdog page. You should see a line that starts with 'module update db'. After it you can read the module that causes the problem.

In my case that was environment_indicator. I'm no PHP developer, so I solved the problem by opening the database in Sequel Pro and checking the version column of the system table of this module.

The file environment_indicator.install shows several updates, the first one creating a table. Since the table was present, I entered its version number (7200) in the system table. Now I was able to run the update.php which showed there were 2 updates. I let it update the database, which ran without problems.

When opening the status page everything was fine and I deleted the watchdog line from the system.install file.

I'm just curious why update.php doesn't find any updates, while status page does.